# Exchange data between threads on Intel Xeon Phi - BSP Model

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, parallel-processing, bulk-synchronous-parallel

I want to develop the Bulk Synchronous Parallel Model on Intel Xeon Phi using only std::thread (no other libraries). I organize the code in 2 classes: Superstep and Worker. 
Superstep class contains a vector of Workers.

superstep.hpp

```cpp
template <typename T>
class SuperStep {
    private:
        int nw;
        std::vector<T> input;
        std::vector<std::vector<T>> chunks;
        std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Worker<T>>> workers;     //vector of pointers
        std::vector<std::vector<T>> output;

    public:
        SuperStep(int n, std::vector<T> input);
        ~SuperStep();
        std::vector<T> get_input();
        int get_parallel_degree();
        template<typename F,typename ...Args>
        void computation(std::function<F(Args...)> b);
        void communication();
};
```

Worker class is a thread wrapper

worker.hpp

```cpp
template <typename T>
class Worker {
    private:
        int id;
        SuperStep<T> *ss;
        std::thread thread;
        std::vector<T> input;
        std::vector<T> output;


    public:
        Worker(int id, SuperStep<T> *s);
        Worker(const Worker&) = delete;
        Worker(Worker &&other);
        Worker& operator=(const Worker&) = delete; 
        Worker& operator=(Worker&&) = delete;
        ~Worker();
        int get_id();
        std::vector<T> get_output();
        void set_input(std::vector<T>, int worker_index);
        template<typename F,typename ...Args>
        void work(std::function<F(Args...)> body);
};
```

When I run computation of a Superstep, each workers calls its work() function that compute worker output from worker input using the template function "body".

```cpp
//Superstep Computation
template<typename T>
template<typename F,typename ...Args>
void SuperStep<T>::computation(std::function<F(Args...)> body)
{
    for (auto &w: workers)
            w->work(body);
}

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

//Worker work function
template<typename T>
template<typename F, typename ...Args>
void Worker<T>::work(std::function<F(Args...)> body)
{
    thread = std::thread{[this,body]()
        { 
            output = body(input);            
        }
    };
}
```

I can't understand how to implement the Communication Phase on a MIC processor like Xeon Phi, or rather how to exchange output of every single worker with other workers. Communication consists to send data to the processor (I don't know how) or save outputs in a duplicated lockable vector (but this seems more "shared memory" approach)?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Given your condition of *"using only std::thread (no other libraries)"*, are you ready to re-implement for example a Hoare's CSP-infrastructure or a `Context()`-free **`inproc://`** transport-class, using a profi, FinTech industry-proven, pure memory-mapped code from ZeroMQ for such smart and yet safe and robust interactions, as one possible solution to your problem?

Comment: @user3666197 Thanks for the reply. Is it mandatory to re-implement a communication infrastructure? I think it was simpler... there's no way to communicate between thread with the only std::thread?
Another solution, I think to send workers output to their single Superstep which contains them in his vector. Is it possible through the Superstep pointer SuperStep<T> *ss despite Superstep instance is in a different core?